# Why do I get Assertion error: 'my absolute path' when writing output time file in PCRaster?

Tags: python, assertion

I work with PCRaster from python, so the error is due to PCRaster.
I initialize my path where I want to save the file:

```
self.SnowPackTime=TimeoutputTimeseries('/home/hydronik/Documents/PROJECTS/SNEG2/data'+self.pathsave+str(self.currentyear)+'snow',self,self.stationmap,noHeader=False)
```

then in dynamic part I take a sample:

```
self.SnowPackTime.sample(Snow)
```

And get an Assertion error:

```
~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pcraster/framework/Timeoutput.py in sample(self, 
expression)
128 
129     if self._userModel.currentTimeStep() == self._userModel.nrTimeSteps():
 --> 130        self._writeTssFile()
131 
132 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pcraster/framework/Timeoutput.py in 
_writeTssFile(self)
151     """
152     #
--> 153     outputFilename =  self._configureOutputFilename(self._outputFilename)
154 
155     outputFile = None

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pcraster/framework/Timeoutput.py in 
_configureOutputFilename(self, filename)
195     prepends sample directory if used in stochastic
196     """
--> 197     assert not os.path.isabs(filename), filename
198 
199     if not os.path.splitext(filename)[1]:

AssertionError: /home/hydronik/Документы/PROJECTS/SNEG2/data/result_1980/1980snow
```

the code in the file of package is following:

```
def _configureOutputFilename(self, filename):
"""
generates filename
appends timeseries file extension if necessary
prepends sample directory if used in stochastic
"""
assert not os.path.isabs(filename), filename

if not os.path.splitext(filename)[1]:
  filename += ".tss"

if hasattr(self._userModel, "nrSamples"):
  filename = os.path.join(str(self._userModel.currentSampleNumber()),
    filename)

return filename
```

Any ideas about the source of this error? The path is absolute

Comment: The `assert` statement is checking that the path is _not_ absolute. Use a relative path instead.

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with your problem, but is the space before "Documents" in "/home/hydronic/ Documents" intentional?

Comment: I saw it, sorry. No, there is no space in my code in reality